# Передача индекса и элемента массива в модальное окно VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Вопрос такой: есть карточки сервисов (которые заполняются запросом с бека) и есть кнопка удалить (по клику которой вызывается метод removeSerivce) Метод удаляет сервис на беке по айди и так-же удаляет карточку реактивным методом splice. Всё хорошо, но возникла потребность сделать окно подтверждения (вы точно уверены что хотите удалить?). И я застрял на этом вопросе, так-как не могу передать индекс элемента массива да и сам элемент внутрь этого окна! Всё перепробовал и никак...подскажите как это сделать проще всего плз! Спасибо!

Мой компонент

```
<v-col v-for="(service,index) in allServices"
                           :key="service.id">
                            <v-card-actions>
                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        color="deep-purple accent-4"
                                        @click="
                                         "
                                >
                                    Редактировать
                                </v-btn>
                                <v-dialog
                                        v-model="dialog"
                                        width="500"
                                >
                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                        <v-btn
                                                text
                                                color="deep-purple accent-4"
                                                dark
                                                v-on="on"
                                        >
                                            Удалить
                                        </v-btn>
                                    </template>

                                    <v-card>
                                        <v-card-title
                                                class="headline red lighten-2"
                                                primary-title
                                        >
                                            Вы уверены?
                                        </v-card-title>

                                        <v-card-text>
                                                Фид будет удалён вместе с площадкой!
                                          </v-card-text>

                                        <v-divider></v-divider>

                                        <v-card-actions>
                                            <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                                            <v-btn
                                                    color="primary"
                                                    text
                                                    @click="
                                                    removeService(service,index)
                                                    dialog = false"
                                            >
                                                Удалить
                                            </v-btn>
                                            <v-btn
                                                    color="primary"
                                                    text
                                                    @click="
                                                    dialog = false"
                                            >
                                                Отмена
                                            </v-btn>

                                        </v-card-actions>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-dialog>

                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
```

Мой метод:

```
export default {
    name: "ServiceCardList",
    methods: { 
        removeService: function (service,index) {
            axios.get('/api/services/delete/'+service.id, {})
                .then((response) => {
                    this.allServices.splice(index, 1);
                })
        }

    },
```

Comment: Метод у Вас принимает индекс элемента. В чем проблема передать в модальное окно этот элемент `this.allServices[index]`?

Comment: так не вышло пишет что null

Comment: removeService(service,index) - работает только так (но индекс null) поэтому удаляется 0 элемент массива

Comment: У Вас еще проблема в том, что метод `removeService` из диалового окна. Я бы так не делал. Как  мне кажется, из диалогового окна, Вы должны получить `true/false`, а потом уже вызывать или нет `removeService`.

Comment: да хорошая идея! то есть как-то поменять метод , чтоб он ждал true/false..я об этом думал но пока не знаю как именно..навренео что-то с промисами (я просто новичок))

Comment: Не нужны здесь промисы. Разбейте задачу на действия. 1) по клику открываете диалоговое окно 2) По закрытию окна - фиксируете результат 3) Решаете - удалять или нет

Comment: Только если не юзать промисы, самая главная проблема остаётся. Я не знаю, как мне передать индекс правильно внутрь окна...

Comment: Зачем, Вам там индекс, без каких- либо данных? Без лишних манипуляций, у детей нет доступа к данным родителя?

Comment: Индекс ,чтобы удалить элемент в массиве правильно динамически.

Comment: А service у Вас нормально передается в метод?

Comment: service нормально передаётся.

Comment: я не знаю... приведите пример, который можно воспроизвести прямо здесь. Тогда можно будет решить проблему

Comment: я попробую сделать по умному не создавать много модалок внутри а создать снаружи + передавать туда индекс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему передачи индекса путём того, что вынес моё модальное окно в другой компонент и передал ему мои service и index.

Это теперь находится на месте моей кнопки и окна:

```
<dialog-window :removeService="removeService" :service="service" :index="index" :dialog="dialog"/>
```

А это сам компонент DialogWindow:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog"
                width="500"
        >

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn
                        text
                        color="deep-purple accent-4"
                        dark
                        v-on="on"
                >
                    Удалить
                </v-btn>
            </template>



            <v-card>
                <v-card-title
                        class="headline red lighten-2"
                        primary-title
                >
                    Вы уверены?
                </v-card-title>

                <v-card-text>
                    Фид <b>{{service.name}}</b> будет удалён вместе с площадкой!
                </v-card-text>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                    <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            text
                            @click="removeService(service,index) ,dialog = false"
                    >
                        Удалить
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            text
                            @click="dialog = false"
                    >
                        Отмена
                    </v-btn>

                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "DialogWindow",
        props: ['service','index', 'removeService','dialog'],

    }
</script>
```

Знаю, что решение не очень то и верное ,так-как на каждый элемент будет создаваться своё модальное окно, но в моём случае компонентов не много. И ещё возникла проблема со свойством dialog (которое отвечает за вызов самого окна). Но её можно решить легко. Вообщем, результатом я доволен. Но в будущем собираюсь разрешить эту проблему (по мере понимания самого Vue).

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так, берите в учет, что мое приложение отличается от приложения автора:

Создал компонент модального окна в который поместил дочерний компонент

```html
<baseModal v-if="isModalShow">
      <editFav
        @showModal="showModal"
        :fav="this.choosedFav"
        :index="this.choosedIndex"
      />
 </baseModal>
```

У родительского компонента добавил необходимых для передачи в дочерний компонент переменных

```js
data() {
    return {
      favs: [],
      isModalShow: false,
      choosedFav: null,
      choosedIndex: null
    };
  }
```

Ну и повесил обработчик на элемент из списка `v-for="(fav, index) in favs"`

```html
<div class="favorites__edit-icon" @click="showModal(fav, index)">
  <i class="el-icon-edit"></i>
</div>
```

И собственно код функции `showModal(fav, index)`

```js
    showModal(fav, index) {
      if (fav) {
        this.choosedFav = fav;
        this.choosedIndex = index;
      }
      this.isModalShow = !this.isModalShow;
    }
```

При клике на элемент из списка функция `showModal(fav, index)` меняет значение выбранных элементов `choosedFav` `choosedIndex`, а также `isModalShow` становится равен `true`, после чего отображается модальное окно и в дочерний компонент передаются вышеназванные переменные

Вообще, как я понимаю, автор сделал почти так же, только компонент модального окна  он отдает каждому элементу списка, а я же вынес модальное окно за список